# How could I overload trait variable

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Hello I have the follwong :

```
trait CarObject{ 
 val name: String
}

def takeCarObject(obj:CarObject)
```

How could I prepare a trait object ,CarObject, and pass it to the method  ?

I have tried :

> private def createCarObject(str: String) = new CarObject {  val name =
>   str}

but the result is n't a CarObject !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does work:

```
scala> trait CarObject { val name: String }
defined trait CarObject

scala> def createCarObject(str: String) = new CarObject { val name = str }
createCarObject: (str: String)java.lang.Object with CarObject

scala> def createCarObject(str: String): CarObject = new CarObject { val name = str }
createCarObject: (str: String)CarObject

scala> val c = createCarObject("bmw")
c: CarObject = $anon$1@5143c423

scala> c.name
res0: String = bmw
```

Notice: If you don't explicitly set a return value to the method, the return value `java.lang.Object with XXX` is inferred, where in this case XXX is `CarObject`.

Comment: Thanks.That's a new info for me .

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try creating it like this:

```
(new CarObject { val name = str}):CarObject
```

The resulting type would be `CarObject`.